# Running small C-Program tooks more then 2 minutes?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, exe, cs50

**UPDATE2**
Changed to another IDE (Codeblocks) - now everthing works fine

**UPDATE**
I would like to mention additonaly that the long run is only when i start the a.exe for the first time - when i started it afterwards again it runs without delay

When i again do a compile - its the same long run as before

---

i compiled this small c-program with the gcc-compiler on windows and try to run it -

**Code:**

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_int("Integer: ");
    printf("hello world");
}
```

I compile the file with the following command without errors:

> gcc temp.c cs50.c

But when i start the finished exe-file (a.exe) it tooks more then 2 minutes to run the program.
After the 2 minutes the program does what it should do.
But why this tooks so long?

Any hints for me?

Comment: So with the program you show, it takes two minutes before the prompt "Integer: " is printed? Or do you just wait two minutes at the prompt before you give some input or press `Enter` so the program can continue?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the `tempc` input file you have when building? What is this `tempc` file? What does it do? Why do you add it when building?

Comment: Why is the executable called `a.exe`?

Comment: @WeatherVane that is the standard name in gcc at least if no name was given.

Comment: Ah thanks, I have never used gcc (soon perhaps).

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I think the same, it should be `a.out`.

Comment: @Sarques perhaps then, because it is hosted on Windows.

Comment: @Sarques `a.out` on POSIX systems, `a.exe` on Windows.

Comment: Yeah sure, got confused @Someprogrammerdude , thanks :)

Comment: @Some programmer dude:
yes it tooks over 2 minutes till the prompt is printed
tempc was a typo - it is the c program temp.c
cs50.c is the library which i have to include cause i want to use the get_int function from there

Comment: Do you build and run this on a local drive in your computer? Is the drive encrypted? Do you have some kind of extra caching enabled? Is this the only program where it happens? Can you replicate it with other programs (your own and others), on other drives, on other (similar) systems?

Comment: It is on a local drive - no ecrpyton - no exrtra caching - every program is slow, even a simple "hello world" (this is a little bit faster but also tooks appr. half a minute) - tried it not on another system/drive.

In the meantime i find a workaround with using the IDE Codeblocks instead - now everything runs smoothly.

Nevertheless thanks for your support!

Comment: From *where* are you running? A Windows command prompt window? A MSYS or Cygwin console window? From inside some IDE?

Comment: In Win7 from cmd